# Post Message to a Microsoft Teams Channel using App

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to post messages to specific Microsoft Teams Channels using Graph REST API (from my app). I'm looking at the following API endpoint, but it says it doesn't support `Application` permission type: [Create chatMessage in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs)

Is there a better way than using the webhook/bots?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we don't have plans for posting messages with application permissions. Only option to send a message to channel using Graph API would be using delegated permission.

Please use [Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-overview?view=msteams-client-js-latest) / [Connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors?view=msteams-client-js-latest) to send messages.